# How are the downvotes and the comments removed?

Tags: discussion

There was an [answer with a downvote](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2366589/11206). After a fruitless discussion with the author I also downvoted the answer. Today I found the answer but the downvotes and all the comments disappeared. There were also some changes in the answer so I looked in its history to check if I find a version with the original text. This was the case and I also found out that the answer was deleted and undeleted. Did this deletion and undeletion of an answer remove the comments and the votes? If so, is it a respectable behavior to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [deleted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2366556/solving-the-inequality-fracxx1-frac1x-3-2-leq-0/2366584#2366584) by the same user with 2 upvotes and 2 downvotes. Two your comments are below that answer.

After you reach 10k reputation, you will be able to [view deleted posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). (And also moderators and the OP can see deleted post, regardless of their reputation.)

Even below that reputation, you should probably see [on your reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) that an answer you downvoted was removed - since you get back the reputation deducted by the downvote. (Make sure you have checked the option *show removed posts*. IIRC the reputation changes related to downvotes are shown only to you - other users don't see them when they look at your reputation tab.)

Comment: thank you, I see now that something related to this question was removed 6 minutes after I downvoted something related to the question. So the answer I commented was deleted and all the votes and comments disappeared with this answer. A new answer was posted with a copy of the text of the old answer. This new answer was deleted  and undeleted and then modified.  The new answer also had the creation  date "yesterday" similar to all other answers to this question. So I thought it was the original question.